# IE9 open link in a new window/tab not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Today I just noticed that Internet Explorer 9 will not open a new window/tab when clicking a link whose `target` is set as `_blank`. It will open the link on same tab itself.

```
<a href="www.mydomain.com" target="_blank">Link should open in new tab</a>
```

**This feature is working on all other versions of IE**

I tried [this solution by microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281679) but not working at all.

Did anyone have a working solution for this bug??

Comment: Is this for a specific website or all websites on your machine? Have you checked your preferences to ensure that `_blank` links open in new tabs or windows as opposed to the same window (don't know the exact preference, don't have IE9 :p)

Comment: Actually one of my client is screaming that his link loading on same tab. He is using IE9. And I'm sure that its a browser problem. All website links are loading like that.

Comment: In IE9 you can control how to open links. In Internet Settings' "General" tab open "Tab settings", there you'll find alternatives for opening links in tab or present window etc. (I'm not sure of the exact terms, my IE is finnish.)

Comment: No. I'm not able to find any workaround. I just told to my client to get the new IE version.

Answer (score 1):

Let's type `http://` before `www.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Hey I just showed an example only as `www.mydomain.com`. The `http://` was already in my code and its not working.

Comment: But It's working on my IE9. You may set some preferences in IE.

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 you can only change TAB settings, there seems to be no place to change window behaviour.

I am also finding that when I try and open pages (any website) in a new window, ie opens it in the same window.

Answer (score -1):

Its not about certain webpages. Something is definetely wrong with IE software. Even when you right click on a link and choose option stating "Open link in a new TAB" it still opens it in new window instead of a tab. This cant be issue with settings as those affect single left click mouse behavior and not a choice where you tell IE to open particular link in TAB! My IE settings although are set to open links in new tabs and same as when pop up is encountered its set to open in new tab. So sofware has issues. Please fix it